# Dynamically add array contents as new elements - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

edit: Problem solved! I was modifying the page before it was loaded so the script didn't actually do anything. I fixed it now and it works. Thanks for the help, I'll have to chalk this one up to being new to jQuery and it's weirdness.

Long story short I'm trying to make a webpage that dynamically takes Article titles, thumbnail images, descriptions, and links to them, and creates a nicely formatted list on the page. I'm trying to accomplish this in jQuery and HTML5.

Here is the sample data that I'll be using to dynamically populate the page. For now formatting isn't important as I can do that later after it works at all.

```
<script>
var newsTitles = ["If It Ain&#39;t Broke, Fix It Anyways"];
var newsPics = ["images/thumbnail_small.png"];
var newsDescs = ["August 14th 2015<br/><b>If It Ain't Broke</b><br/>Author: Gill Yurick<br/><br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sometimes, a solution isn't the only one. So how do we justify changes to systems that don't need to be fixed or changed? I explore various systems from other successful card games and how their approaches to issues (be they successes or failures in the eyes of the deisgners) can help us create EC."];
var newsLinks = ["it_aint_broke-gill_popson.html"];
var newsIndex = 0;
var newsMax = 1;
```

The section of code where I'm trying to use the contents of the arrays above to dynamically fill elements.

```
<td style="height:500px;width:480px;background-color:#FFF7D7;padding:20px" colspan=2 id="article">
    <h1>Articles</h1>
    <!-- the column  for each news peice add an element with the thumbnail, the title and teh desc -->
    <script>
        for(i = 0; i < newsMax; i++) { 
            $("#articleList").append("<h3 href=&quot;" newsLinks[i] + "&quot;>" + newsTitles[i] + "</h3>", "<img src=&quot;"newsPics[i] + "&quot;>","<p>" + newsDesc[i] + "</p>", ); $("div").append("hello");
        }
    </script>
    <div id="articleList">
        HELLO
    </div>
</td>
```

Here is what it ends up looking like, I can post more info if needed as I am aware this may not be clear enough to fully explain my problem but I am unable to determine that. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Any errors in the console? You can access Console by using `F12`.

Comment: Missing proper quotes for attributes and `+` in string concatenation. Can't replace `"` with `&quote;` for attribute quotes

Comment: @ParthTrivedi no, that is invalid using `&quote;`

Answer (score 0):

The following string is invalid html and is missing a `+`

```
"<h3 href=&quot;" newsLinks[i] + "&quot;>"
```

You need to use proper quotes for html attributes, not `&quote;`

Try

```
"<h3 href='" + newsLinks[i] + "'>"
```

OR

```
"<h3 href=\"" + newsLinks[i] + "\">" // `\` used to escape same type quote
```

Personally I prefer opening/closing html strings with single quotes but either will work

Note tht you should be getting a syntax error thrown in dev tools console which would have helped you locate problems

Comment: thanks, I changed the things you suggested but it isn't working, gonna have to do some debugging myself to figure it out. I wasn't aware of the dev tool console, this is my first attempt at building a webpage that wasn't pure HTML and CSS, so I'm pretty unaware of alot of this stuff. Plus I couldn't find a good description of the difference between the different ways to add quotes that gave the reasons why to use each one.

I'm in a plain text editor for now as it's all I have, well Notepad++ anyways so I missed the spelling mistake for the other thing and feel like a fool for it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for(i = 0; i < newsMax; i++) { 
    $("#articleList").append("<h3 href=&quot;"+ newsLinks[i] + "&quot;>" + newsTitles[i] + "</h3>, <img src=&quot;"+newsPics[i] + "&quot;>, <p>" + newsDescs[i] + "</p>" ); $("div").append("hello");
}
```

Concatation issue + typo for newsDescs

Comment: `try this` doesn't explain what was changed or why it should work

Comment: It was concatenation issue. And newsDesc is not defined it is newsDescs. you forgot 's' at the end of variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(i = 0; i < newsMax; i++) { 
        $("#articleList").append("<h3 href='" + newsLinks[i] + "'>" + newsTitles[i] + "</h3>");
        $("#articleList").append("<img src='" + newsPics[i] + "'>","<p>" + newsDesc[i] + "</p>" ); 

    }
```